# Save date in db using mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to save date in mysql db in php, but couldnt figure the problem out

Code is:

```
$effectiveDate = strtotime("+1 hours", strtotime($time));
$new_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$effectiveDate);
mysql_query('UPDATE table SET date=$new_date WHERE id='.$row['id']);
```

but the date never changes

Whats the problem?

Comment: You should always check for errors from your queries. Add `or die(mysql_error())` after the `mysql_query` call.

Comment: **$effectiveDate = strtotime("+1 hours", $time);** isn't it?

Comment: $time is actually date read from db, so its actually a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need quotes around the date:

```
mysql_query('UPDATE table SET date="$new_date" WHERE id='.$row['id']) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: it changes the date to 0000:00:00 00:00:00

Comment: I have used echo $new_date, it shows the right date, e.g. 
2015-04-01 01:00:00

Comment: Then I can't see any reason why it would set the date to 0000.